# Draw loglog graph using pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using a `pyplot` to draw loglog graph. Here is the code:

```
data = [...] # a list of int values
from scipy.stats import itemfreq
tmp = itemfreq(data) # Get the item frequencies
x = tmp[:, 0] # unique values in data
y = tmp[:, 1] # freq

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.loglog(x, y, basex=2, basey=2)
plt.show()
```

And I get this image:
[image: Loglog plot]

But I don't want the data points to be connected by lines which seems very ugly. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the [`plt.loglog()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.loglog) function several different keyword arguments which will change the format of your plot, such as `linestyle`, `marker`, and their respective colours.

```
data = [...] # a list of int values
from scipy.stats import itemfreq
tmp = itemfreq(data) # Get the item frequencies
x = tmp[:, 0] # unique values in data
y = tmp[:, 1] # freq

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.loglog(x, y, basex=2, basey=2, linestyle='None', 
           marker='x', markeredgecolor='red')
plt.show()
```

Alternatively you can give a string as a third positional argument which can select the formatting in a simpler way, such as `plt.loglog(x, y, 'rx')` which will give the same formatting as above (no line with red crosses). The format string arguments available can be found [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot).

Comment: I must say the matplotlib documentation is misleading, which says the 'marker' parameter is unknown...Anyway, thanks!